# Disabling Mutliple Row Selection in Tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm new to Swift and I want to disable multiple row selection in my tableview. I try to implement different type of approaches and my final code block is below, which is not working.
Thanks for your help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        companyTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark;
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if selectedCells.contains(indexPath.row) {
                selectedCells.remove(indexPath.row)
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            } else {
                selectedCells.insert(indexPath.row)
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `allowsMultipleSelection = false` works fine.

Comment: By default single selection is only selected in storyboard. In storyboard--> select your tableview and under attribute inspector there is a selection option of No, Single selection, Multiple Selection. If you don't want to change it at run time you can set it from storyboard. Also default value for `allowsMultipleSelection` is also false.

Comment: Show the `cellForRowAtindexPath` code.

Comment: Priyal, I already selected 'Single Selection' in Storyboard but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if !selectedCells.contains(indexPath){
            selectedCells.add(indexPath)

            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if selectedCells.contains(indexPath){
            selectedCells.remove(indexPath)

            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the `cellForRowAt` use this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if selectedCells.contains(indexPath){
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Hey Poles, I already selected 'Single Selection' in Storyboard but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Then I think the problems lies in the code `didSelectRowAt` portion. Your Single Selection is working but the way you are setting checkmarks, has some fault.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem in your select/deselect call. Use something like this:
Here I have an array of selectedCells(the size of which equals the number of total number of cells)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        if filteredStudents.count > indexPath.row {
            selectedCells[indexPath.row] = true
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        if selectedStudents.count > indexPath.row {
            selectedCells[indexPath.row] = false
        }
    }
```