# iOS 13 UITableView select/deselect problems

Tags: swift, uitableview, select, ios13, uiswitch

I have in my project UITableView that works great with ios 12 and lower, but with new update for ios 13 now it started to happening multiple issues.

selection is working in a way that i get last indexPath, but i have in code that for selected row i change background, now background stays selected for every row that i select not just last one, and i did set that i can select only one row.

If i scroll selected row at indexPath 3 for example have different background and when i scroll since table have 90 rows every 10th or 15th is selected also even if i didn't select it.

And last thing that is probably connected to that is: 
i have in every row switch with who i do some actions depending on witch row is selected, when i select first is ok, but when i deselect and select other one the first stays remembered somewhere and i can't select next, so at that point nothing is selected and i can't no longer select anything.

Again everything is working with ios 12 and lower.

How can i fix this?

This is part of my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //   return self.patientData.arrayNames.count
    return structuredNames.count;
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:PatientExercizeCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exercizeCell") as! PatientExercizeCell
    cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row

    cell.exercizeName.text = structuredNames[indexPath.row][1]
    cell.appName.text = structuredNames[indexPath.row][0]
    cell.dateOfExercize.text = structuredNames[indexPath.row][2] + " " + structuredNames[indexPath.row][3]

    if(!listOfNotes.isEmpty){
        if(listOfNotes[indexPath.row] != ""){
            cell.noteButton.isHidden = false
            cell.noteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        }else{

            cell.noteButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    if(fileHandler.listOfFilesFromDevice.contains(fileNames[indexPath.row]) && patientIsSended && !(leftoverFiles.contains(fileNames[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: ".t")[0]))){
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    }else{
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
    }

    if(GlobalSession.checkedExercises.contains(indexPath.row)){
        cell.checkMark.isOn = true
    }else{
        cell.checkMark.isOn = false
    }
    return cell
}


// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    indexPathNumber = indexPath.row
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Color().blue()


}
```

[Video about difference between ios 12 and 13](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hs6uifzono39qau/AAArox11maWjbnTqUrEGRddLa?dl=0)

Comment: Can you upload a video recording of the view on both iOS12 and iOS13?

Comment: here you go, i put video on dropbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it because recycle behaviors of the cell

My suggestion is

1. in tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:) don't change the background color, just add the selected row to array and reload data
2. in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) set the background color depends on the array selected row

Comment: thanks different approach solved the table selection problem, other one with switch i found different solution

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- Disable multiple row selection
- Reset the background color in `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

Also take a look at this similar question: [Disabling Mutliple Row Selection in Tableview in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089206/disabling-mutliple-row-selection-in-tableview-in-swift)

Comment: it's disabled since i have in storyboard selected single selection

and i did try to reset it with tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:), but than i have problem that when i scroll indexes resets so index goes only to 15 for example that is visible on screen

i have 90 records in table but index goes to 15 and no further

Comment: The problem lays somewhere else then, maybe the way you populate `structuredNames`.

Comment: could be, don't know, it's complicated how i populate it but i did not have problem with that so far, and now also it displays correctly names and data inside table, problem appears with selecting

but this is strange that i changed absolutely nothing, same version of application is both on ios 12 and ios 13, and on one is working perfectly,  on other problems with same code

Comment: iOS 13 is the buggiest release ever I'd say. Can you upload some code on git?

Comment: i can't since it's a project from company i work in

Comment: I see, probably there is something wrong with loading data.